# Prevent Form Validation CSS .error from highlighting textbox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using the form validation JQuery plugin, and I have everything working quite well, except for one particular thing.

I am using the error class in CSS to stylize how the error text looks like so:

```
.error {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #2d0004;
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```

However, whenever I get an error (a required field not being filled), the inputbox is also affected by the CSS styling shown above. How can I prevent the CSS styling shown above from affecting the input field associated with the error, and only apply the style to the error text?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This explains it well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891798/jquery-validate-plugin-error-css

Comment: If both cases are errors, wouldn't it make sense for them to look the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.error:not(input) {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #2d0004;
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```